# Weird behaviour hover event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code on some absolute positioned divs on a page:

**JS/JQUERY:**

```
$("div.do").hover(function(){          
$(this).stop().next('.tooltip').fadeIn();    
}, function(){
 $(this).stop().next('.tooltip').fadeOut();     
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="do"></div>
<div class="do"></div>
<div class="do"></div>
```

When hovering over an event using `console.log($(this))`  returns multiple events firing in a very sporadic way.  it seems like they are being trigger multiple times.  I have been using jQuery for quite some time and never experienced anything like this.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us the do-something parts?

Comment: is there any strange css involved?  You say they are absolutely positioned.  Is their container position relative?

Comment: @John parent element is relative and has fixed height / width. on some of the hovers the event will just keep repeating and the mouse is stationary.  Im at a loss.

Comment: @jnolte which browser are you using?

Comment: @John FF 4.0  Same behaviour in Safari :(

Comment: @jnolte Hrmmm... it's hard to say w/o being there.  My best advice is to isolate/change some variables to see where its happening.  I'm convinced that its something to do with CSS (either jQuery animations or the fact that you have them positioned absolute).  Try removing the animations, use a simple show/hide.  Position them staticly.  Are they still firing randomly?  If so, then we can almost eliminate any CSS issues.  After that, get rid of hover, instead do a bind('mouseenter mouseleave') check the event type in an if statement.  Let me know how this works out and we'll go from there.

Comment: @Jon, good insight. I think i have pinpointed the issue. it seems that depending on the location the tooltip that appears is sometimes appearing directly in the path of the hover (parent element) and causing the event to fire repetedly.  What is the best way to target this so the tooltips (also positioned absolutely) do not interefere with the first hover event?

Answer (score 1):

works like a charm for me > http://jsfiddle.net/ekxxC/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle of almost the same thing you posted.  It's working exactly as I would imagine.  See if your code is any different:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyLNn/4/

I highlighted the divs in red so you can see where the target area is.